# Unify AMP & Non-AMP Consent Flow

Tags: javascript, cookies, amp-html

We're currently setting up an advanced user consent flow for both the AMP Version of our website as well as the "normal" version.

In an effort to keep friction as low as possible we'd like to check for already given consent when navigating between AMP and Non-AMP content.

- for the normal consent flow we set a cookie which we can check for in the `checkconsentHref` call and suppress the AMP consent message when the given cookie as already set
- for the AMP flow we use the `amp-consent` component which depending on the response sets an encrypted item in LocalStorage

This works fine when a user comes from a Non-AMP page and navigates to an AMP page after as we can check for the cookie server-side and then suppress the AMP-consent altogether.

However when a user comes from an AMP page first the LocalStore item looks similar to this `eyJ2diI6eyJhbXAtY29uc2VudDpjb29raWUtY29uc2VudCI6eyJ2Ijp7InMiOjF9LCJ0IjoxNTc1NDcxNTcwNzM2fX18` which makes it hard to check if that's a reject or accept out of the box.

Has anyone implemented a similar use case yet or has a hint on how to check for consent the other way round?

Comment: any progress on this, I have the same situation and would like to know how you fix it please

Answer (score 0):

Set a localStorage entry for the non-AMP-page AND the AMP-page (same key) and simply check on the non-AMP-page if the storage exists and is not empty. If there is an entry, don't show the cookie consent.

When a user navigates from a AMP-page to a non-AMP-page, the cookie consent doesn't have to be confirmed again since the script on the non-AMP-page checks if there is already an entry in localStorage or not. (The amp-consent uses the URL as key for the localStorage.) This way the user has still to confirm the consent in case he navigates from a non-AMP-page to a AMP-page, but this case is highly unlikely.

[see also here](https://www.iubenda.com/en/help/3182-amp-html-cookie-dialog-box)

Comment: It seems this is not possible anymore as chrome now have different buckets for the localstorage of websites depending if you enter normally or through an iframe